# puppetrun is automatically called in foreman for every 3 min. how to stop this

Tags: puppet, foreman

Please check the attached screenshot, puppetrun is called repeatedly for every 3 min and its keep on running certain critical services repeatedly. I want puppetrun to be called on demand. not an automated call like this.
In puppet.conf file, Do I have to enable any parameters to stop this repeated puppetrun invoke ? or I have to make any changes in foreman ?
or is it the puppetmaster triggering this call on all clients ?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean every 30 minutes? The screenshot shows only three runs, possibly within a two hour period.

Usually the Puppet agent is running as a service which can be stopped and disabled - commands vary depending on your OS. For a systemd-based OS:

```
systemctl stop puppet
systemctl disable puppet
```

`service puppet stop` should at least stop it on others, check your OS docs for commands to disable the service at startup.

However when using Puppet, it should be perfectly safe for the agent to run continually and ensure state. The catalog shouldn't be affecting a service every time it runs, it suggests an error.

Comment: ah thx... but how about If I have war deployment to glassfish servers which should happen only on demand...?

Comment: Also, I can use runinterval=--no-client right? in puppet.conf [agent] section ?

Comment: for software config state, it's perfectly legal to run agent every 30 min. but my use case is different...what If I have a puppet module to deploy war over 100s over web servers using foreman... I don't want this to be happen on every 30 min...

Comment: a) I don't know about your war deployment. Sounds like it shouldn't be executed on every run.

Comment: b) `--no-client` isn't a value of runinterval, it's a command line option that is passed to puppet agent on startup (through your service manager, init script options etc).

Comment: okay understood... Do you have any idea for war deployment?. Like is it possible to skip certain puppet modules from puppetrun ? or is it better to keep deployment in jenkins ?